# Leaflet - Gray stripes after panning

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, leaflet

**EDIT**

This question is **not** a duplicate of [How to get a leaflet map canvas to have a 100% height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588601/how-to-get-a-leaflet-map-canvas-to-have-a-100-height) as for the obvious reason, that you can see my map spanning the 100% height (compare the attribution on my picture being in the gray zone, while the container of the other question obviously ends before the blank zone. Also i can identify the size of my container spanning the 100% of the parent container in the developer tools. Just take a look at my css and and a very close look at the picture and maybe at leaftlet if you don't know how it works.)

**Original**

I use leaflet 1.5.1 in ionic 3.

After panning the map a bit, oftentimes the contents for gray parts are not being loaded (no network requests/traffic indicated in my browsers dev tools) and i am left with gray parts/stripes in the map as in the picture (the gray horizontal stripe below).

When i pan a lot further the missing map parts are loaded, but sometimes not (especially in iOS).

[image]

My map **page**'s HTML using my map component (below)

`<map style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">`

The map **component**'s HTML

`<div id='map'></div>`

The **component**'s **scss** file

```
map {
    #map{
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And here the **component's typescript** which creates the map

```
this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: L.LatLng(center.latitude, center.longitude),
      zoom: 13,
      attribution: Attribution,
      tap: false
    });


    //Add OSM Layer
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", { attribution: Attribution }).addTo(this.map);

    this.map.setView([center.latitude, center.longitude], 14);
```

Any hints on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246815/data-toggle-tab-does-not-download-leaflet-map/36257493#36257493

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a leaflet map canvas to have a 100% height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588601/how-to-get-a-leaflet-map-canvas-to-have-a-100-height)

Comment: @IvanSanchez if you take a look at the picture of my question and the question you mark my question as a duplicate on, you may see a big difference... Mine is already 100% in height (As in the css)  => no duplicate. Chrome Developer tools also confirm that.

Comment: @ghybs i'll take a look at this. May very well be a tabs problem as described in your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to trigger a resizing event via `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))` every time the user enters the tab page holding all the tabs including the map tab.

The map is reacting to this by adjusting itself to the "new" size.